# iOS Navigation bar that changes between views?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I wasn't really sure how to phrase this question, so I did the best I could.  I'm trying to design a UI for my app and my views are in a navigation controller.

My goal is to get my VIEW1 to have a transparent navigation bar with bar button items on it, and have VIEW2 with a translucent navigation bar.  Sort of like Snapchat's UI when transitioning from the camera to a different view [(example)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6V5GU_pygoY&t=1m18s).

I have tried using the

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

in VIEW1's `viewWillAppear`: method.  I also used the opposite in VIEW2's `viewWillAppear`: method.

This is the closest I've gotten to getting this effect, however when going back, the navigation bar disappears before VIEW2 leaves the screen.
I would like it to follow VIEW2 off the screen (like Snapchats).
I also would like the navigation bar in VIEW 1 to be transparent instead of hidden.

I have also tried not setting them up in a navigation controller and giving them each separate navigation bars.  However, the problem is that the navigation bar doesn't reach under the status bar.

Any advice is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

pls try this

This code in view1 viewWillAppear

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {

```
[super viewWillAppear:YES];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;  // optional

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

}

This code will add on view2 viewWillAppear

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

```
[super viewWillAppear:YES];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent; 

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

}

Sweet & smart coding..........